# How to create transition where 2 routes are shown at the same time? React

Tags: reactjs, animation, transition, router

Is there a way to create [this pages transition animation](https://pizzapizza.io/work) with React Router 6? Mb Frame Motion can do this?

Thanks!

I tried to do following on Click event: 1) change visible page view (into small like in PizzaPizza) 2) inside setTimeOut navigate route and show next page. It works, but not smooth enough :(

I also tried [Chrome API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/view-transitions/) for transitions, didn't work out for me.